# How to add mute/unmute for the sound menu in gnome shell?

Tags: 11.10, sound, gnome, mute, indicator-sound

The sound menu in gnome shell have no mute/unmute option.
[image: gnome-shell sound menu]
so if the sound is muted i have to open Sound Settings and unmute it,unlike unity
[image: Unity sound menu]

i,e, i want to add a mute/Unmute button to gnome shell sound menu, as i need it frequently.

Comment: you should check this site https://extensions.gnome.org/ to see if they have any extension that can help you.

Comment: No, i don't think there is a gnome-shell extension for it.so i ask ???

Comment: Your best option is to post this as a bug/feature request with Gnome here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi

Answer (score 5):

You may find the following gnome shell extension useful to do this. It allows switching audio as well as muting and unmuting.

https://extensions.gnome.org/review/1220

Answer (score 0):

Middle click on the sound icon mutes/unmutes the sound (at least in Unity it does).